# Laravel redirection error when setting up multiple authentication guard

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes

I have set up an admin authentication guard as per described in this tutorial:
[Laravel Multiple Auth Tutorial](https://lavalite.org/blog/multiple-authentication-in-laravel)
**Routes**

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'namespace' => 'Auth'
], function() {

    Route::get('/login', 'AdminController@showLogin')->name('admin.show.login');
    Route::post('/login', 'AdminController@login')->name('admin.login');

    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'auth:admin'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.home');
        Route::get('/logout', 'AdminController@logout');
    });    
});
```

**Controller**

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }

    public function index() 
    {
        return "Admin authenticated";
    }

    public function showLogin() 
    {
        return view('admin.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $admin = Admin::where('login_id', $request->input('login'))->firstOrFail();
        Auth::guard('admin')->loginUsingId($admin->id, TRUE);
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.home'));
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        return redirect()->route('admin.show.login');
    }
}
```

**`RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    switch ($guard) 
    {
        case 'admin':
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) 
            {
                return redirect()->route('admin.home');
            }
            break;

        default:
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/home');
            }
            break;
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

**Exception handler**

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception) 
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) 
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);
    switch  ($guard) 
    {
        case 'admin':
            $login = 'admin.show.login';
            break;

        default:
            $login = 'login';
            break;
    }
    return redirect()->guest(route($login));
}
```

When `/admin` is accessed without loggin in, the `/admin/login` view is correctly. After logged in, the `/admin` URL is casuing infinite redirect loop error. The admin can be successfully logged out using `/admin/logout` route. The problem seems to be the cause of `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware. Am I missing something?

Comment: RedirectIfAuthenticated is the route `guest` middleware is not a global one, please check  `app/HTTP/Kernel.php`. Also take a look at the comment at the bottom of the tutorial you linked.

Comment: Your comment enlightened me. Never notice that `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware is mapped by `guest` keyword.

Comment: yes is a common misconception about what is really doing RedirectIfAuthenticated, the name is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your problem happens in the `AdminController`, specifically the constructor function.

The redirection loop happens on route `/admin` because the middleware is conflicting with `auth:admin` middleware (in the routes) and `guest:admin` middleware (in the controller).

What you want is to apply the `guest:admin` middleware to all except `index` and `logout` function:

```
$this->middleware('guest:admin', ['except' => ['index', 'logout']]);
```

Comment: I applied like the following `$this->middleware('auth:admin', ['except' => ['index', 'logout']]);` since there is a default user auth guard for users. However, the redirect loop error is occurring on `/admin/login` and `/admin` is opened for all access.

Comment: @M.Ko, sorry my bad, the middleware should be `guest:admin`. I already updated my answer above